# Below images are hiding if we mouse-over on above image

Tags: html, css

If we mouse-over on 1st image in  `code snippet`, image which is present in 2nd row-2nd column [**Blackberry image**] will hide, if we mouse-out than again blackberry image will be visible. Instead of hiding complete image, i just want to override `dropdown-options` on image. 
[demo link](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/cases-covers.html)

**before mouse-over** [ **blackberry image visible** ]

[image]

**after mouse-over** [ **blackberry image hidden** ]

[image]

```css
#narrow-by-list { display :none;}
.choose1 
{ 
text-transform: capitalize; 
text-align: center;
font-weight:bold;
font-size:18px;
color: #000000;
}
.links1234 { color : #908983;}
.links1234:hover { color : #f85700;}


.grow {
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 23%;
  margin: 5px 1% 5px 1%;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  transition: height 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: height 0.5s;
  text-align: center;
  background-color : #fff;
  
}
.grow:hover ul{
  display: block;
}

.grow:hover + .grow + .grow + .grow + .grow {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.grow ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px;
  list-style: none;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.25);
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.grow img{
  width: 100%;
}

.expand 
{
 position:relative;
 right:8px;
 top:4px;
}
```

```html
<h2 class ="choose1">
  Choose Your Brand
</h2>

<div class="grow">
  <img class = "expand" src="http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/media/cases/apple.png" onmouseover="this.src='http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/media/cases/apple_active.png'"
onmouseout="this.src='http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/media/cases/apple.png'"
border="0" alt=""/>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a class="links1234" href = "http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/cases-covers/art-graphics/iphone-4.html">Apple Iphone 4</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="links1234" href = "http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/cases-covers/art-graphics/iphone-4s.html">Apple Iphone 4s </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="grow">
  <img class = "expand" src="http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/media/cases/apple.png" onmouseover="this.src='http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/media/cases/apple_active.png'"
onmouseout="this.src='http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/media/cases/apple.png'"
border="0" alt=""/>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a class="links1234" href = "http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/cases-covers/art-graphics/iphone-4.html">Apple Iphone 4</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="links1234" href = "http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/cases-covers/art-graphics/iphone-4s.html">Apple Iphone 4s </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="links1234" href = "http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/cases-covers/art-graphics/iphone-4s.html">Apple Iphone 4s </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="links1234" href = "http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/cases-covers/art-graphics/iphone-4s.html">Apple Iphone 4s </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="links1234" href = "http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/cases-covers/art-graphics/iphone-4s.html">Apple Iphone 4s </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="links1234" href = "http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/cases-covers/art-graphics/iphone-4s.html">Apple Iphone 4s </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="links1234" href = "http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/cases-covers/art-graphics/iphone-4s.html">Apple Iphone 4s </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="links1234" href = "http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/cases-covers/art-graphics/iphone-4s.html">Apple Iphone 4s </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="grow">
  <img class = "expand" src="http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/media/cases/apple.png" onmouseover="this.src='http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/media/cases/apple_active.png'"
onmouseout="this.src='http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/media/cases/apple.png'"
border="0" alt=""/>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a class="links1234" href = "http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/cases-covers/art-graphics/iphone-4.html">Apple Iphone 4</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="links1234" href = "http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/cases-covers/art-graphics/iphone-4s.html">Apple Iphone 4s </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="grow">
  <img class = "expand" src="http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/media/cases/apple.png" onmouseover="this.src='http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/media/cases/apple_active.png'"
onmouseout="this.src='http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/media/cases/apple.png'"
border="0" alt=""/>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a class="links1234" href = "http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/cases-covers/art-graphics/iphone-4.html">Apple Iphone 4</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="links1234" href = "http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/cases-covers/art-graphics/iphone-4s.html">Apple Iphone 4s </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="grow">
  <img class = "expand" src="http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/media/cases/blackberry.png" onmouseover="this.src='http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/media/cases/blackberry_active.png'"
onmouseout="this.src='http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/media/cases/blackberry.png'"
border="0" alt=""/>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a class="links1234" href = "http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/cases-covers/art-graphics/iphone-4.html">Apple Iphone 4</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="links1234" href = "http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/cases-covers/art-graphics/iphone-4s.html">Apple Iphone 4s </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="grow">
  <img class = "expand" src="http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/media/cases/apple.png" onmouseover="this.src='http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/media/cases/apple_active.png'"
onmouseout="this.src='http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/media/cases/apple.png'"
border="0" alt=""/>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a class="links1234" href = "http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/cases-covers/art-graphics/iphone-4.html">Apple Iphone 4</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="links1234" href = "http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/cases-covers/art-graphics/iphone-4s.html">Apple Iphone 4s </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="grow">
  <img class = "expand" src="http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/media/cases/apple.png" onmouseover="this.src='http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/media/cases/apple_active.png'"
onmouseout="this.src='http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/media/cases/apple.png'"
border="0" alt=""/>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a class="links1234" href = "http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/cases-covers/art-graphics/iphone-4.html">Apple Iphone 4</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="links1234" href = "http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/cases-covers/art-graphics/iphone-4s.html">Apple Iphone 4s </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="grow">
  <img class = "expand" src="http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/media/cases/apple.png" onmouseover="this.src='http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/media/cases/apple_active.png'"
onmouseout="this.src='http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/media/cases/apple.png'"
border="0" alt=""/>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a class="links1234" href = "http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/cases-covers/art-graphics/iphone-4.html">Apple Iphone 4</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="links1234" href = "http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/cases-covers/art-graphics/iphone-4s.html">Apple Iphone 4s </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="grow">
  <img class = "expand" src="http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/media/cases/apple.png" onmouseover="this.src='http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/media/cases/apple_active.png'"
onmouseout="this.src='http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/media/cases/apple.png'"
border="0" alt=""/>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a class="links1234" href = "http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/cases-covers/art-graphics/iphone-4.html">Apple Iphone 4</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="links1234" href = "http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/cases-covers/art-graphics/iphone-4s.html">Apple Iphone 4s </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="grow">
  <img class = "expand" src="http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/media/cases/apple.png" onmouseover="this.src='http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/media/cases/apple_active.png'"
onmouseout="this.src='http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/media/cases/apple.png'"
border="0" alt=""/>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a class="links1234" href = "http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/cases-covers/art-graphics/iphone-4.html">Apple Iphone 4</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="links1234" href = "http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/cases-covers/art-graphics/iphone-4s.html">Apple Iphone 4s </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="grow">
  <img class = "expand" src="http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/media/cases/apple.png" onmouseover="this.src='http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/media/cases/apple_active.png'"
onmouseout="this.src='http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/media/cases/apple.png'"
border="0" alt=""/>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a class="links1234" href = "http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/cases-covers/art-graphics/iphone-4.html">Apple Iphone 4</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="links1234" href = "http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/cases-covers/art-graphics/iphone-4s.html">Apple Iphone 4s </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="grow">
  <img class = "expand" src="http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/media/cases/apple.png" onmouseover="this.src='http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/media/cases/apple_active.png'"
onmouseout="this.src='http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/media/cases/apple.png'"
border="0" alt=""/>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a class="links1234" href = "http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/cases-covers/art-graphics/iphone-4.html">Apple Iphone 4</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="links1234" href = "http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/cases-covers/art-graphics/iphone-4s.html">Apple Iphone 4s </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="grow">
  <img class = "expand" src="http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/media/cases/apple.png" onmouseover="this.src='http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/media/cases/apple_active.png'"
onmouseout="this.src='http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/media/cases/apple.png'"
border="0" alt=""/>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a class="links1234" href = "http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/cases-covers/art-graphics/iphone-4.html">Apple Iphone 4</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="links1234" href = "http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/cases-covers/art-graphics/iphone-4s.html">Apple Iphone 4s </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="grow">
  <img class = "expand" src="http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/media/cases/apple.png" onmouseover="this.src='http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/media/cases/apple_active.png'"
onmouseout="this.src='http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/media/cases/apple.png'"
border="0" alt=""/>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a class="links1234" href = "http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/cases-covers/art-graphics/iphone-4.html">Apple Iphone 4</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="links1234" href = "http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/cases-covers/art-graphics/iphone-4s.html">Apple Iphone 4s </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="grow">
  <img class = "expand" src="http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/media/cases/apple.png" onmouseover="this.src='http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/media/cases/apple_active.png'"
onmouseout="this.src='http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/media/cases/apple.png'"
border="0" alt=""/>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a class="links1234" href = "http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/cases-covers/art-graphics/iphone-4.html">Apple Iphone 4</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="links1234" href = "http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/cases-covers/art-graphics/iphone-4s.html">Apple Iphone 4s </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="grow">
  <img class = "expand" src="http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/media/cases/apple.png" onmouseover="this.src='http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/media/cases/apple_active.png'"
onmouseout="this.src='http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/media/cases/apple.png'"
border="0" alt=""/>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a class="links1234" href = "http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/cases-covers/art-graphics/iphone-4.html">Apple Iphone 4</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="links1234" href = "http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/cases-covers/art-graphics/iphone-4s.html">Apple Iphone 4s </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

This question is not duplicate as in other question problem was `images were pushing outside` , but here images are completely invisible....

Comment: change css for the class `grow`

Comment: can you please explain more

Comment: @user5348fh8y5 so you want to keep blackberry image as it is or what?

Comment: Duplicate of your own, previous question [below Images are pushing once we mouse over on above image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39702278/below-images-are-pushing-once-we-mouse-over-on-above-image)

Comment: @SagarKodte i want to keep `blackberry` image as it is after i mouse-over also, but those drop-down options should override on below image.....

Comment: @CBroe thanks for commenting here, in that question images were not hiding but pushing away , but in this question complete images are not visible after `mouse-over`......

Comment: You are still trying to achieve the same thing though, no? In that case, you should update your original question.

Comment: @CBroe that is completely different , after i used the code present in answer, now images are completely hiding now.... but i requested the same in that question as because client wanted that before, now they want to over-ride images now.....

Comment: @CBroe Thanks for your support, i got solution.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope You want this or something else?

```css
#narrow-by-list { display :none;}
.choose1 
{ 
text-transform: capitalize; 
text-align: center;
font-weight:bold;
font-size:18px;
color: #000000;
}
.links1234 { color : #908983;}
.links1234:hover { color : #f85700;}


.grow {
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 23%;
  margin: 5px 1% 5px 1%;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  transition: height 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: height 0.5s;
  text-align: center;
  background-color : #fff;
  
}
.grow:hover ul{
  display: block;
}

.grow ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px;
  list-style: none;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.25);
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.grow img{
  width: 100%;
}

.expand 
{
 position:relative;
 right:8px;
 top:4px;
}
```

```html
<h2 class ="choose1">
  Choose Your Brand
</h2>

<div class="grow">
  <img class = "expand" src="http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/media/cases/apple.png" onmouseover="this.src='http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/media/cases/apple_active.png'"
onmouseout="this.src='http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/media/cases/apple.png'"
border="0" alt=""/>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a class="links1234" href = "http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/cases-covers/art-graphics/iphone-4.html">Apple Iphone 4</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="links1234" href = "http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/cases-covers/art-graphics/iphone-4s.html">Apple Iphone 4s </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="grow">
  <img class = "expand" src="http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/media/cases/apple.png" onmouseover="this.src='http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/media/cases/apple_active.png'"
onmouseout="this.src='http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/media/cases/apple.png'"
border="0" alt=""/>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a class="links1234" href = "http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/cases-covers/art-graphics/iphone-4.html">Apple Iphone 4</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="links1234" href = "http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/cases-covers/art-graphics/iphone-4s.html">Apple Iphone 4s </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="links1234" href = "http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/cases-covers/art-graphics/iphone-4s.html">Apple Iphone 4s </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="links1234" href = "http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/cases-covers/art-graphics/iphone-4s.html">Apple Iphone 4s </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="links1234" href = "http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/cases-covers/art-graphics/iphone-4s.html">Apple Iphone 4s </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="links1234" href = "http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/cases-covers/art-graphics/iphone-4s.html">Apple Iphone 4s </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="links1234" href = "http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/cases-covers/art-graphics/iphone-4s.html">Apple Iphone 4s </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="links1234" href = "http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/cases-covers/art-graphics/iphone-4s.html">Apple Iphone 4s </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="grow">
  <img class = "expand" src="http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/media/cases/apple.png" onmouseover="this.src='http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/media/cases/apple_active.png'"
onmouseout="this.src='http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/media/cases/apple.png'"
border="0" alt=""/>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a class="links1234" href = "http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/cases-covers/art-graphics/iphone-4.html">Apple Iphone 4</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="links1234" href = "http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/cases-covers/art-graphics/iphone-4s.html">Apple Iphone 4s </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="grow">
  <img class = "expand" src="http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/media/cases/apple.png" onmouseover="this.src='http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/media/cases/apple_active.png'"
onmouseout="this.src='http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/media/cases/apple.png'"
border="0" alt=""/>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a class="links1234" href = "http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/cases-covers/art-graphics/iphone-4.html">Apple Iphone 4</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="links1234" href = "http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/cases-covers/art-graphics/iphone-4s.html">Apple Iphone 4s </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="grow">
  <img class = "expand" src="http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/media/cases/blackberry.png" onmouseover="this.src='http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/media/cases/blackberry_active.png'"
onmouseout="this.src='http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/media/cases/blackberry.png'"
border="0" alt=""/>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a class="links1234" href = "http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/cases-covers/art-graphics/iphone-4.html">Apple Iphone 4</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="links1234" href = "http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/cases-covers/art-graphics/iphone-4s.html">Apple Iphone 4s </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="grow">
  <img class = "expand" src="http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/media/cases/apple.png" onmouseover="this.src='http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/media/cases/apple_active.png'"
onmouseout="this.src='http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/media/cases/apple.png'"
border="0" alt=""/>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a class="links1234" href = "http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/cases-covers/art-graphics/iphone-4.html">Apple Iphone 4</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="links1234" href = "http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/cases-covers/art-graphics/iphone-4s.html">Apple Iphone 4s </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="grow">
  <img class = "expand" src="http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/media/cases/apple.png" onmouseover="this.src='http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/media/cases/apple_active.png'"
onmouseout="this.src='http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/media/cases/apple.png'"
border="0" alt=""/>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a class="links1234" href = "http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/cases-covers/art-graphics/iphone-4.html">Apple Iphone 4</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="links1234" href = "http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/cases-covers/art-graphics/iphone-4s.html">Apple Iphone 4s </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="grow">
  <img class = "expand" src="http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/media/cases/apple.png" onmouseover="this.src='http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/media/cases/apple_active.png'"
onmouseout="this.src='http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/media/cases/apple.png'"
border="0" alt=""/>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a class="links1234" href = "http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/cases-covers/art-graphics/iphone-4.html">Apple Iphone 4</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="links1234" href = "http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/cases-covers/art-graphics/iphone-4s.html">Apple Iphone 4s </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="grow">
  <img class = "expand" src="http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/media/cases/apple.png" onmouseover="this.src='http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/media/cases/apple_active.png'"
onmouseout="this.src='http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/media/cases/apple.png'"
border="0" alt=""/>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a class="links1234" href = "http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/cases-covers/art-graphics/iphone-4.html">Apple Iphone 4</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="links1234" href = "http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/cases-covers/art-graphics/iphone-4s.html">Apple Iphone 4s </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="grow">
  <img class = "expand" src="http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/media/cases/apple.png" onmouseover="this.src='http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/media/cases/apple_active.png'"
onmouseout="this.src='http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/media/cases/apple.png'"
border="0" alt=""/>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a class="links1234" href = "http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/cases-covers/art-graphics/iphone-4.html">Apple Iphone 4</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="links1234" href = "http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/cases-covers/art-graphics/iphone-4s.html">Apple Iphone 4s </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="grow">
  <img class = "expand" src="http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/media/cases/apple.png" onmouseover="this.src='http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/media/cases/apple_active.png'"
onmouseout="this.src='http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/media/cases/apple.png'"
border="0" alt=""/>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a class="links1234" href = "http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/cases-covers/art-graphics/iphone-4.html">Apple Iphone 4</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="links1234" href = "http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/cases-covers/art-graphics/iphone-4s.html">Apple Iphone 4s </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="grow">
  <img class = "expand" src="http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/media/cases/apple.png" onmouseover="this.src='http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/media/cases/apple_active.png'"
onmouseout="this.src='http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/media/cases/apple.png'"
border="0" alt=""/>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a class="links1234" href = "http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/cases-covers/art-graphics/iphone-4.html">Apple Iphone 4</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="links1234" href = "http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/cases-covers/art-graphics/iphone-4s.html">Apple Iphone 4s </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="grow">
  <img class = "expand" src="http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/media/cases/apple.png" onmouseover="this.src='http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/media/cases/apple_active.png'"
onmouseout="this.src='http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/media/cases/apple.png'"
border="0" alt=""/>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a class="links1234" href = "http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/cases-covers/art-graphics/iphone-4.html">Apple Iphone 4</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="links1234" href = "http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/cases-covers/art-graphics/iphone-4s.html">Apple Iphone 4s </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="grow">
  <img class = "expand" src="http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/media/cases/apple.png" onmouseover="this.src='http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/media/cases/apple_active.png'"
onmouseout="this.src='http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/media/cases/apple.png'"
border="0" alt=""/>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a class="links1234" href = "http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/cases-covers/art-graphics/iphone-4.html">Apple Iphone 4</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="links1234" href = "http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/cases-covers/art-graphics/iphone-4s.html">Apple Iphone 4s </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="grow">
  <img class = "expand" src="http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/media/cases/apple.png" onmouseover="this.src='http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/media/cases/apple_active.png'"
onmouseout="this.src='http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/media/cases/apple.png'"
border="0" alt=""/>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a class="links1234" href = "http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/cases-covers/art-graphics/iphone-4.html">Apple Iphone 4</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="links1234" href = "http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/cases-covers/art-graphics/iphone-4s.html">Apple Iphone 4s </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="grow">
  <img class = "expand" src="http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/media/cases/apple.png" onmouseover="this.src='http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/media/cases/apple_active.png'"
onmouseout="this.src='http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/media/cases/apple.png'"
border="0" alt=""/>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a class="links1234" href = "http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/cases-covers/art-graphics/iphone-4.html">Apple Iphone 4</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="links1234" href = "http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/cases-covers/art-graphics/iphone-4s.html">Apple Iphone 4s </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.grow:hover + .grow + .grow + .grow + .grow
{
  visibility: hidden;
}

You have to just remove above property from CSS.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.choose1 
{ 
text-transform: capitalize; 
text-align: center;
font-weight:bold;
font-size:18px;
color: #000000;
}
.links1234 { color : #908983;}
.links1234:hover { color : #f85700;}


.grow {
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 23%;
  margin: 5px 1% 5px 1%;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  transition: height 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: height 0.5s;
  text-align: center;
  background-color : #fff;

}
.grow:hover ul{
  display: block;
}


.grow ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px;
  list-style: none;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.25);
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.grow img{
  width: 100%;
}
```